# How to add css classes to a child view from handlebar template

Tags: ember.js

I would like to add a css class to a child view from a handlebars template. I am currently getting an error as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'get'
```

My code is as follows:

```
App = Ember.Application.create()

App.ParentView = Ember.View.extend({
    foo: 'bar',
    content: 'Hello',
    ChildView: Ember.View.extend({
        classNames: this.get('parentView').get('classesToAdd')
    })
});
```

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sohara/PKMTn/2/

Is there something special about the classNames property that shifts the context from the Ember.View to a dom element? Or perhaps there's some other way that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite the `init` on the view to access `classesToAdd`, see http://jsfiddle.net/WCjda/1/

**Handlebars:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view App.ParentView}}
       {{#view ChildView classesToAdd="my-class"}}
            hello        
       {{/view}}
    {{/view}}
</script>​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
App = Ember.Application.create()

App.ParentView = Ember.View.extend({
    foo: 'bar',
    content: 'Hello',
    ChildView: Ember.View.extend({
        init: function() {
            this._super();
            var classes = this.get('classesToAdd');
            this.set('classNames', Ember.makeArray(classes));
        }
    })
});​
```

Comment: Thanks. This was basically what I was trying to achieve. I wanted to dry up the handlebars templates. Here's a jsfiddle that is even more dry: http://jsfiddle.net/sohara/WCjda/3/ - No need to declare the childView in the template. One thing to note: I later realized I could achieve the same effect by more creative use of css selectors. (Just declare a class on the parentView and then make a selector along the lines of div.my-class div {#...css attributes }. But this keeps my css cleaner.

Comment: One thing to note, setting the classes like this breaks the event handling for the child view because the regular ember-view class is not added to the array of class names, rather the array is replaced. Here's an updated fiddle with a possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/sohara/WCjda/4/  And here's a further discussion of the issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/490

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `this` in your `classNames` declaration of your ChildView because the view object has not been instantiated.

However, you can use bindings.  See the documentation at Emberjs.com under the "Customizing the HTML Element" section.

Comment: I had actually tried that first. I had set classNamesBinding and I got another error.